# Image of police car -> dynamically draw police car number

Tags: arcgis-engine, c#

Let's say I have 10 police cars using the same image, and I want each one to be numbered 1 - 10, but the number 1 is dynamically drawn on top of the police car image.  What is the class / interface  I use for that with C# and ArcEngine 10.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd use a multilayer markersymbol with two symbol layers.  The bottom symbol would be a picturemarkersymbol of a police car.  On top of that would be one or more charactermarkersymbols, with the car number set via ICharactermarkersymbol.CharacterIndex.

As I've said before, you really need to get <del>Arcview</del> arcmap if you haven't already done so. It has interactive symbol editing that would allow you to create symbols interactively, save them to a file that your arcengine app could then load. Defining these symbols without <del>arcview (or desktop)</del> arcmap will be quite tedious.

Comment: Wouldn't you recommend ArcInfo over ArcView in this case since it has greater functionality, or do you really think ArcView will suffice?

Comment: At the current version of ArcGIS, ArcInfo is a license level, not a product. An ArcInfo license can be checked out when using ArcMap (or ArcCatalog) to do certain types of editing. I _think_ Kirk is referring to the entire ArcGIS suite when he mentions ArcView (and, if not, I'd appreciate a little enlightenment from him as well). See [here](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/about/gis-for-me.html) for details regarding what you get with a specific license level.

Comment: To use an interactive symbol editor, as found in arcmap, at minimum you would need ArcView.  I think 90 day eval licenses are available.

Answer (score 2):

Kirk was right.  Here's the code if anyone wants it.

```
  IDynamicGlyph createMultiGlyph(String imagePathName, String text, int fontSize, System.Drawing.FontStyle fontstyle = System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, String fontType = "Arial")
    {
        IMultiLayerMarkerSymbol multiLayerMarkerSymbol = new MultiLayerMarkerSymbolClass();
        pictureMarkerSymbol = new PictureMarkerSymbolClass();
        pictureMarkerSymbol.CreateMarkerSymbolFromFile(esriIPictureType.esriIPictureBitmap, imagePathName);
        pictureMarkerSymbol.Size = 100;
        IColor whiteTransparencyColor = ESRI.ArcGIS.ADF.Connection.Local.Converter.ToRGBColor(Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255)) as IColor;
        pictureMarkerSymbol.BitmapTransparencyColor = whiteTransparencyColor;
        multiLayerMarkerSymbol.AddLayer(pictureMarkerSymbol);

        List<int> asciiList = stringToAscii(text);

        int pixelsBetweenLetters = 2;
        int numLetters = text.Length;
        int widthOfAllSpaces = (numLetters -1) * pixelsBetweenLetters;
        int adjustmentMultiplier = 3; //TextRenderer.MeasureText is not perfect

        int width = 0; 
        for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
        {
            SizeF size = TextRenderer.MeasureText(text[i].ToString(), new Font(fontType, fontSize, fontstyle));
            width = ((width + Convert.ToInt32(size.Width)) / adjustmentMultiplier); 
        }
        int negativeXoffset = -1 * ((width + widthOfAllSpaces) / 2);
        int currentOffset = negativeXoffset; 

        for (int i = 0; i < asciiList.Count; i++)
        {
            ICharacterMarkerSymbol characterMarkerSymbol = new CharacterMarkerSymbolClass();
            Font arialFont = new Font(fontType, fontSize, fontstyle);
            characterMarkerSymbol.Font = ESRI.ArcGIS.ADF.Connection.Local.Converter.ToStdFont(arialFont);
            characterMarkerSymbol.Size = fontSize;
            characterMarkerSymbol.Color = SymbolCreator.getColor(255, 0, 0) as IColor;
            characterMarkerSymbol.XOffset = currentOffset;
            characterMarkerSymbol.CharacterIndex = asciiList[i];
            multiLayerMarkerSymbol.AddLayer(characterMarkerSymbol);

            SizeF size = TextRenderer.MeasureText(text[i].ToString(), new Font(fontType, fontSize));
            currentOffset += Convert.ToInt32(size.Width / adjustmentMultiplier) + pixelsBetweenLetters; 
        }

        IDynamicGlyph returnGlyph = dynamicGlyphFactory.CreateDynamicGlyph((ISymbol)multiLayerMarkerSymbol);
        return returnGlyph; 
    }


       public List<int> stringToAscii(String stringToConvert)
            {
                List<int> asciiList = new List<int>(); 
                for (int i = 0; i < stringToConvert.Length; i++)
                {
                    char c = stringToConvert[i];
                    byte b = (byte)c;
                    asciiList.Add(b); 
                }
                return asciiList; 
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

First I would consider using standard **labeling mechanisms**. If this approach is insufficient, I suggest looking into **custom renderers** (IFeatureRenderer). You could also employ custom layers but I guess that is unnecessary in your case.

But, if your objects (cars) change position very often, you will want to work with dynamic display.